# macOS not installing properly on A1502 Macbook 13 inch

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hard-drive, install, ssd

I'm trying to install macOS Catalina on a new SSD and the hard drive is showing up in my installation however, once the installation is about to complete the computer restarts and goes back to recovery mode.

If I try to boot without the usb drive I get a folder with a question mark on it.

I saw in another post that they have replaced the hard drive cable and it worked but from my understanding, the Macbook I have (A1502) is a direct plug into the logic board. Any idea what I can do from here?

Comment: I'm afraid A1502 covers 9 different models - could you hone it down from this list - https://everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/?search_keywords=a1502

Comment: hey @Tetsujin I believe the model is MacBook Pro 13-Inch "Core i5" 2.4 Late 2013 from the list. On the back (without the case) it says model A1493 if that helps. thanks for the response.